# extracting jboss metrics using jmx_exporter and jboss 5.2.0 version

Tags: jboss, jmx-exporter

I'm  very new to jboss.
I want to extract jboss metrics from my application using jmx_exporter. I'm working with version 5.2.0 of jboss and centos 7.
the available docs are using jboss 7 so I didn't find any help in the doc or the examples in internet.
I want just to extract some specefic jboss metrics and not all of them.
Here is an exemple of what I did:

```
---
lowercaseOutputName: true
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
whitelistObjectNames:
- "jboss.jca:*"
rules:
- pattern: 'jboss.jca<name=(.*),type=null,attribute=ConnectionCount>'
  name: jboss_jca_managedconnectionpool_connectioncount
  help: JBoss JCA ManagedConnectionPool Connection Count
  labels:
    name: $1
  type: GAUGE
```

But it is not giving a result
someone can help please?